# android how to keep gps open and locked

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I'm working on a project to get geolocation within 10 seconds interval via gps on android. I'm using a background service to do it,i'm using `requestLocationUpdates` to get exact location, problem is 10 seconds is not enough time for GPS lock it's usually takes 20 seconds to 1 minute exact lock, to fix that problem i'm increasing time interval to 3 minutes,then gps activating,locking to satellite and getting exact geolocation. But after getting exact location GPS going to sleep and GPS icon disappear from screen,until to next update. There is `stopUsingGPS()` in the class but i'm not calling or using in anywhere in my code. As you guys know when you open yandex navi or google maps it keeps GPS open and locked until you destroy the application,how i can do the same ? I've tried this approach [Android: How to keep GPS active until more accurate location is provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993016/android-how-to-keep-gps-active-until-more-accurate-location-is-provided) but result was the same, GPS icon appears, locking to satellite,getting geolocation and going to sleep, how i can keep GPS open and locked until i stop the service ?

PS : I know that kind of method will drain the battery very quickly but in this project battery life is not important. Also i'm a beginner about Android Studio,i've used and edited class from StackOverflow,if you guys can explain the solution it will be great for me.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my GPSTracker Class;

```
package com.atalay.reporter.Control;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import com.atalay.reporter.Service.Reporter;

/**
 * Created by BARISUSER on 9.12.2015.
 */
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    double speed;

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;


    public GPSTracker(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(mContext.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                //B.A. 08.12.2015 TODO: Buradan devam et
                showSettingsAlert();
            } else
            {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null)
                    {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            speed = location.getSpeed();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                speed = location.getSpeed();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getSpeed ()
    {
        if(location != null)
        {
            speed = location.getSpeed();
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 0;
        }
    return speed;
    }
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null)
        {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Reporter.aktifEnlem = location.getLatitude();
        Reporter.aktifBoylam = location.getLongitude();
        Reporter.hiz = location.getSpeed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

My Reporter Class;

```
package com.atalay.reporter.Service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import com.atalay.reporter.Common.ApiHelper;
import com.atalay.reporter.Common.Utils;
import com.atalay.reporter.Control.GPSTracker;

/**
 * Created by BARISUSER on 7.12.2015.
 */
public class Reporter  extends Service {
    final static long Dakika = 10000;
    private ApiHelper apiHelper;
    private GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    public static double aktifEnlem = 0;
    public static double aktifBoylam = 0;
    public static double hiz = 0;
    private boolean ilkKonum = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        apiHelper = new ApiHelper();
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(Reporter.this);
        if(!ilkKonum){
            if(aktifBoylam==0 || aktifEnlem==0)
                if(gpsTracker.canGetLocation()){
                    aktifEnlem = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
                    aktifBoylam = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
                    hiz = gpsTracker.getSpeed();
                }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        //gpsTracker.stopUsingGPS();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true)
                {
                    try {

                        if (Utils.InternetControl(Reporter.this.getApplicationContext())) {
                            isYap();
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(Dakika * 1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public String getIMEI(Context context)
    {

        TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei = mngr.getDeviceId();
        return imei;

    }
    private void isYap()
    {
        if(aktifBoylam!=0 || aktifEnlem!=0)
        {

            apiHelper.setParam("enlem", aktifEnlem);
            apiHelper.setParam("boylam", aktifBoylam);
            apiHelper.setParam("hiz", Math.round(hiz/1000));//hiz means speed
            apiHelper.setParam("cid", getIMEI(this));
            apiHelper.responseString(ApiHelper.ResponseType.POST);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/05/android-gps-positioning-location-strategies/ go through this link